# cordova-plugins-file-transfer from npm prevent deviceready to fire

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

When using phone gap build the deviceready event does not fire when using the newest cordova-plugins-file-transfer (1.2.0). I'm also using the cordova-plugins-file from npm (2.0.0 or 2.1.0).

If I remove the cordova-plugins-file-transfer line from my config.xml and rebuild the app, the deviceready event fires as normal.

Can someone explain what is going on? Everything works fine when when I use the iOS emulator.

Comment: how you call the device ready event ? I ionic, I don't remember the reason but it's better to use :     ionic.Platform.ready(function() { });

Comment: I call it like this: $ionicPlatform.ready(). Using it this way did not cause a problem before, the app ran fine. However, I will try your suggestions. Do you know why its better to use ionic.Platform.ready()?

Comment: using ionic.Platform.ready() did not solve my problem.

Comment: it's better to use ionicPlatform.ready rather than document.ready function. But not difference in my opinino from $ionicPlatform & ionic.Platform

Comment: Where does the problem occur? iOS device or desktop browser?